# Send two mails in one /post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

My issue is simple - sometimes one of the mails is not being sent. My code:

```
api.post('/sendMail', (req, res) => {
   transporter.sendMail(someFunc(), (err) => { // send mail to one user
      if (err) {  
         res.status(500).send('error');
      }

      res.status(200).send('success');
   });

   transporter.sendMail(someFunc(), (err) => {  // send mail to second user
      if (err) {  
         res.status(500).send('error');
      }

      res.status(200).send('success');
   });
});
```

as above - sometimes one of the mails is not being sent.

**Question**: Should code responsible  for sending second mail be inside callback of first mail? Or it's totally okey to keep them separate like in the code above? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will likely fail in a lot of cases. You can't tell Express to answer with two different status codes, you have to decide *once* which code and response you send.

> Should code responsible for sending second mail be inside callback of first mail ?

Yes, that could be a way, however that has two downsides

1) it doesn't scale well (do that for four, three, ... ten thousands of emails ...)

2) it doesn't scale well performance wise as that would send one email after another, you could send them in parallel instead:

To do that, promisify sending mails:

```
const sendMail = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  transporter.sendMail(someFunc(), (err) => { 
    if(err) reject(err) else resolve();
  });
});
```

Then it is as easy as:

```
Promise.all([ sendMail(), sendMail() ])
 .then(() => res.status(200).send("success"));
 .catch(() => res.status(500).send("failure"));
```